# Locale / UTC offset on Marketing cloud sends to DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have contacts subscribed to classes in different time zones.

They should receive an email 1 hour prior to class start.

We thought of storing all class times in UTC-6:00, since Automation Studio works on this time and will be able to pick these up with SQL queries to initiate the sends.

Then, we have three options:

1. Store the UTC Offset for each class (processed by Ampscript on send)
2. Store the UTC Offset for each Contact (processed by Ampscript on send)
3. Store the original class time to display besides the UTC-6:00 time field.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

We tend to go with option #3 to increase readability for the non-technical users.

In any case, looks like the following **LocalDateToSystemDate** function will not work - this would work only for users, or is there a way to use this?

Extract from documentation:

```
%%[

var @localDate, @systemDate
set @localDate = Now(1)
set @systemDate  = LocalDateToSystemDate(@localDate)

]%%
localDate: %%=v(@localDate)=%%
<br>systemDate: %%=v(@systemDate)=%%
```

Comment: about storing. I think you're pretty spot on already. I'd just store all three things in properly named fields: servertime (utc-6) for in-system compatibility (think getdate() in queries, now(),...); localtime for your users. offset for on-the-fly calculations using ampscript / ssjs / sql.

Comment: have you looked at JB and wait by attribute?

Comment: @JonasLamberty, thanks for the feedback! I think We'd go with storing #1 and #3, as these are physical classes, and unlikely that the contact has a different timezone than where the class is conducted.
EazyE, yup, thanks for the idea, but this doesn't resolve the difference between systemTime and actual timezone for the class or contact. Also, assuming people can book multiple classes weeks ahead, and might cancel by the time the class happens, do we want them injected and waiting? then filter on Contact data after the wait by attribute? debate-able. Thanks for jumping in!